# Fetch several tables in SAP Adobe form

Tags: abap, adobe-form

I am creating an Invoice in SAP Adobeforms and I am using a BAdI to get the data. I need to get the item details which belong to 5 different tables `komv`, `vbrk`, `vbap`, `vbrp`, `t001z`.

How do I proceed to get the data in the interface of the Adobe Form?

Comment: I have a vague idea that I must make an index table for storing the index values , because I need to display the delivery details for each document and then for each delivery , I need to display the item details. I am using the badi BADI_SD_BIL_PRINT01 in IDES.

Answer (score 1):

In the transaction **SFP** you can edit your adobeform. So in the Interface of the adobeform is a section called initialization...
There you can implement your code for the adobeform.

[image: Interface Code Implementation]

Comment: Thank You Raphael.